# For $r\to 0$ $[\log(\log(r^2+1))-\log(\log(2))]^2r=[2\log(r)+o(\log(r))]^2r$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove as part of another problem that the following integral written in polar coordinates is finite, but I am having trouble with the Taylor expansions and landau's o symbol  I guess

$\int_0^1[\log(\log(r^2+1))-\log(\log(2))]^2rdr$.

My lecturer wrote that because $\log(1+r^2)=r^2+o(r^2), r\to 0$, we have:
$[\log(\log(r^2+1))-\log(\log(2))]^2r=[2\log(r)+o(\log(r))]^2r =o(1)$, for $r\to 0$
**I just can't make sense of the first equality.**

I have that for $r\to 0$
$[\log(\log(r^2+1))-\log(\log(2))]^2r=[\log(r^2+o(r^2))-\log(\log(2))]^2r$.

**I am stuck here**, I can't use another taylor expansion in $\log(r^2+o(r^2))$, because the argument is not of the form "1 +(something infinitesimal)", so I can't use $\log(1+y)=y+o(y), y\to 0$

**How does this symplifies to  $[2log(r)+o(\log(r))]^2r$** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logarithm rules to factor out the $r^2$: \begin{align*}\log(\log(r^2 + 1)) - \log(\log(2)) &\sim 
\log(r^2 + o(r^2)) - \log(\log(2)) \\
&=
\log(r^2) + \log(1 + o(r^2)/r^2) - \log(\log(2))
\\
&\sim \log(r^2) + o(1) - \log(\log(2))
\\
&\sim \log(r^2) + o(\log(r)) \end{align*}
The $o(1)$ vanishes as $r \to 0$, but $\log(\log(2))$ is a constant, so I believe the lecturer is calling it $o(\log(r))$.

Comment: I am not very sure how that second log simplies to o(1) step by step (Intuitively I agree). Also then we would end up with $\log(r^2 )+ o(1)+o(\log(r))$, and how does the sum of little  o's become $o(\log(r))$?

Comment: Just note that 
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \log(1 + o(r^2)/r^2) = \log(1)$$
because $\log$ is continuous and $\log(1) = 0,$ so we see $\log(1 + o(r^2)/r^2)$ is $o(1)$. 

I'm not sure if your lecturer is arriving at this some other way, but $\log(\log(2)$ is a constant, so we know that $$\lim_{r \to 0} \log(\log(2))/\log(r) =0.$$ That's where the $o(\log(r))$ comes from.

Comment: Yes, if we have -log(log(2))=o(log(r)), we still need to prove that o(log r)+o(1) =o(1)

Comment: It's not true that $o(\log(r))$ is $o(1)$, just consider the function $f(r) = |\log(r)^{1/2}|.$ We see that
$$\lim_{r \to 0} f(r)/\log(r) = 0, \lim_{r \to 0} f(r)/1 = \infty$$

Comment: you are right, I am sorry I meant $o(\log r)+o(1)=o(\log r)$

Comment: Which seems to be the same, but that is what the chain of equalities yields

$\sim \log(r^2) + o(1) - \log(\log(2)) \sim \log(r^2) + o(1) - o(\log (r))$ which must simplify to $ \sim \log(r^2) + o(\log (r))$

Comment: What you did in the line above is true, yea.